# Error : while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed'

Tags: ios, image

I am running app in ios 7.1 (4S device).when i am calling camaraview for pic photos then i am getting rhis error :
"while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed"

please provide solution.
thanks in advance.

i have allready tried this

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

```
    UIImagePickerController  *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.editing = NO;
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [imagePicker setAllowsEditing:NO];
   imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;


    BOOL cameraAvailableFlag = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    if (cameraAvailableFlag)
    {
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{
    }];}
});
```

full error message is this := Attempting to begin a modal transition from  to  while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed

Comment: Please provide question.

Comment: try to run in main queue

Comment: Add the code you have tried.

Comment: hi i am opening photoView controller class from one other class and , when view did load call of photoview controller then i call UiimagePickerview Controller for capture photo from camara so hasl open. but after 2-3 itration app is crashing and giving error which is above mention  Error : while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed so please provide solution for that where i am wrong or what is the right solution for tis error.

Comment: That isn't a complete error message.  What's before "while a transition is already in progress"?

Comment: Attempting to begin a modal transition from to while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed

Comment: OK so it look like the code you show is not in `viewDidAppear`?  Where is it?

Comment: this is in ViewDidLoad of view controller

Comment: Well there is your answer.

Comment: yes its my answer i have write this code in viewdidload

Comment: **Move it to `viewDidAppear`**.  How many more clues do you need?

Comment: i have write this code in viewdidappear but now camara is continuously appering after capturing photo . sorry i ask question again .

Comment: That's a different question.